# Alter an object recursively and return an observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, observable

Here is my problem .. I have a way that I want to encrypt a body request and make my request. But, to encrypt the data, I use a resource of my company and, that resource encrypt the data and return an Observable .. Let me show the code ..

```
public encryptBodyRequest<T>(obj: T): Observable<T> {
        Object.keys(obj)
            .forEach((property) => {
                if (obj[property] instanceof Object) {
                    this.encryptBodyRequest(obj[property]);
                } else {
                    this.resource.encrypt(obj[property])
                        .subscribe((encrypted) => obj[property] = encrypted);
                }
            });

        return Observable.of(obj);
}
```

On the other side, I have a block code that makes it ...

```
let req = {
    name: '',
    age: '30',
    address: {
       street: '3th avenue',
       num: '120',
       city: {
          zipcode: '10',
          name: 'city name',
          province: 'province name'
       }
    }
};

return this.encryptBodyRequest(req)
           .flatMap((_req) => this.method.post(url, _req));
```

When my 'req' parameter is passed to method that make the request, he isn't encrypted .. he returns like the original `let req`.
He is only encrypted inside `subscribe`, in the `encryptBodyRequest` method.

Note: this `let req` is only an example.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you’re waiting for the various calls to `this.resource.encrypt` to complete.

Comment: There is something what can I do to wait that job complete and then execute my post method?